# How can we use Azure Databricks (Pyspark) to consume event hubs from azure event hubs using using Azure AD service principal?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I want some help with the code snippet used to consume events from Azure EventHubs using PySpark and using Azure AD service principal to do it.

( I do not want to use scala for it)

---

P.S.

1. Structure of my Java Project

[image]

2. Results of the execution in Pyspark

[image]

3. Error message

[image]

Comment: Please add whatever you've tried so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to use some Java-based code to plug-in into the Azure EventHubs connector, similar to [what is shown in the connector's documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/use-aad-authentication-pyspark.md).

But you can also grab [this project](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/kafka-eventhubs-aad-auth), compile it into `jar` file and attach it to cluster/job.  And then you can easily use configure it to use service principal for authentication:

```py
topic = "..."
tenant_id = "..."
client_id = "..."
client_secret = dbutils.secrets.get("secret_scope", "sp-secret")
ehs_ns_name = "eventhubs-namespace-name"
callback_class_name = "net.alexott.demos.eventhubs_aad.ServicePrincipalCredentialsAuth"
# Instead of `servicebus.windows.net` there could be regional endpoints
ehs_endpoint = f"sb://{ehs_ns_name}.servicebus.windows.net"

# EventHubs connection string.
connectionString = f"Endpoint=sb://{ehs_ns_name}.servicebus.windows.net;EntityPath={topic}"

# Parameters that will be passed to the callback function
params = {
  "aad_tenant_id": tenant_id,
  "aad_client_id": client_id,
  "aad_client_secret": client_secret,
}

# Spark EventHubs options
ehConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString': sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString),
  'eventhubs.useAadAuth': True,
  'eventhubs.aadAuthCallback': callback_class_name,
  'eventhubs.AadAuthCallbackParams': json.dumps(params),
}

df = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(**ehConf).load()
```

Because the code is written in Java it shouldn't be Scala version dependent.  And it also supports access to EventHubs via Kafka protocol, also authenticated via AAD tokens.

Comment: Hi @alexott  - I am not good with Java - would you mind explaining if the code in Github  is the actual code snippet and just needs parameterization or some changes are needed to it ?

Comment: you need to compile that code into jar, attach to the cluster/job, and use

Comment: Hi @alexott - I did all the steps as mentioned and now while executing the "Class Not Found" error.  Attached the image(s) to the question above.

Comment: It looks like you didn’t attach a library for eventhubs itself or attached a wrong version